How many 2-Sylow subgroups are contained in this matrix group?
Let $G$ be the group of matrices of the form
\begin{pmatrix}
x&0&a\\
0&1&b\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
with $x, a, b \in \mathbb{Z}/(5)$ and $x$ invertible. How many $2$-Sylow subgroups does $G$ contain?
I know that $G$ has $100$ elements, so the $2$-Sylows have order $4$. I have found that the $10$ matrices with $x \in \{2,3\}$ and $b = 0$ have order $4$ (and they are the only elements of order $4$), which implies the existence of $5$ (and only $5$) cyclic $2$-Sylows. Are there any of the form $C_2 \times C_2$? There would have to be $20$ of them. I have found $5$ elements of order $2$ (those with $x = 4$ and $b = 0$), hence $5$ subgroups of order $2$, which aren't enough to make $20$ subgroups (I guess the elements of order $2$ don't commute).
This is how I got $5$, which I think is correct, but it was very computational in the beginning and very hand-wavy at the end. I have a feeling there must be a better way.

Out of interest: what group is this isomorphic to?  Does anyone know?

This looks suspiciously like the subgroup $H$ of $P\Gamma L_3(5)$ that fixes each point in a given line $L$. Suppose that $L$ is given by $X=0$, then $H$ is isomorphic the group of matrices of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}a & 0 & 0 \\ b & 1 & 0 \\ c & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ with $a\neq 0$.

The group $H$ is not isomorphic to this group though, because the $5$-Sylow-subgroups (obtained by setting the diagonal element to $1$) aren’t isomorphic. In $H$’s cases they are abelian, and that’s not the case in this group.

@Jan both groups have order 100, so their Sylow $5$-subgroups have order $25$ and therefore are abelian. In fact, in both cases they are elementary abelian. It is true that the groups are not isomorphic though. The group in the OP is $C_5\times F_{20}$, whereas your group is $C_5\rtimes F_{20}$. The easiest way to tell them apart is that, in the OP, a Sylow $2$-subgroup centralises a group of order $5$, whereas in your example, a Sylow $2$-subgroup acts faithfully on the (normal) Sylow $5$-subgroup.

Oops, of course, I missed that. What does $F_{20}$ denote? I found something suggesting it might denote a Frobenius group?

All $p$-Sylow subgroups for a particular prime $p$ are isomorphic, so no $2$-Sylow subgroup is isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$ since you already found cyclic $2$-Sylow subgroups. Remember that one of the Sylow theorems states that all  Sylow subgroups are conjugate to each other, and it easily seen that conjugation with an element $g$ is a group automorphism.
